# securitymanager.dll Exception access violation (c0000005)

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1

I have a problem with Explorer.exe, it keeps crashing after it ran for a minute and 5 seconds (says Soluto). I am experiencing this problem since I edited the file/folder permissions of Program Files (x86). I allready set the permissions back to normal, ran the most extended chkdsk and also ran sfc /scannow but it didn't solve anything, also tried a system restore to a couple of days back but that also doesn't work.

I am running Win8.1 (standard edition) on a Lenovo G500s

I added some information (also from Soluto)

http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/52ed22a9340ac9-39598821

**EDIT:**

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13613450/explorer.exe.13780.dmp

Didn't zip it, just uploaded it to my dropbox

Comment: create a dump (http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ), zip and upload the dump. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed my problem... To keep a long story short; I uninstalled Gimp.

Detailed story:

1. AVG tried to repair securitymanager.dll (part of Gimp) because AVG thought it was a trojan horse.
2. Gimp and Explorer.exe didn't know how to handle this file which was broken so Explorer.exe crashed everytime it tried to load securitymanager.dll (which was always after 1 minute and 5 seconds).